# Linq To SQL : Include Child Collection of Child

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, linq-to-sql

So I have a sqlite database. 
Foo has a 1 to 1 relationship to a type Bar. 
Bar has a 1 to many relationship with type Baz

I am using LinqToSql.

If I use a query to get all Bars with children Baz objects like this:

```
        IEnumerable<MeleeWeapon> returnValue;
        using (var connection = GetDatabaseConnection())
        using (var context = new DataContext(connection))
        {
            context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

            var options = new DataLoadOptions();
            options.LoadWith<MeleeWeapon>(mw => mw.Attacks);

            context.LoadOptions = options;

            var query =
                from
                    meleeWeapon in context.GetTable<MeleeWeapon>() 
                select
                    meleeWeapon;


            returnValue = query.ToArray();

        }

        return returnValue;
```

I am successful.

If I use a query to get all foos that have a bar like this:

```
        IEnumerable<Item> returnValue;
        using (var connection = GetDatabaseConnection())
        using (var context = new DataContext(connection))
        {
            context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

            var options = new DataLoadOptions();
            options.LoadWith<Item>(i => i.MeleeWeaponInformation);

            context.LoadOptions = options;

            var query =
                from
                    item in context.GetTable<Item>()
                where
                    item.MeleeWeaponInformation.Any()
                select
                    item;


            returnValue = query.ToArray();

        }

        return returnValue;
```

I am successful.

Inexplicably, if I use a query to get all foos that contain bars, with all bats that belong to said bars like this:

```
        IEnumerable<Item> returnValue;
        using (var connection = GetDatabaseConnection())
        using (var context = new DataContext(connection))
        {
            context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;


            var options = new DataLoadOptions();
            options.LoadWith<Item>(i => i.MeleeWeaponInformation);
            options.LoadWith((MeleeWeapon mw) => mw.Attacks);


            context.LoadOptions = options;

            var query =
                from
                    item in context.GetTable<Item>()
                where
                    item.MeleeWeaponInformation.Any()
                select
                    item;


            returnValue = query.ToArray();

        }

        return returnValue;
```

I get an invalidCastException on the line with query.ToArray()

The one guess I had is that two of the tables have a column named Id (Foo.Id and Baz.Id; Bar being a 1 to 1 with foo, the foreign/primary key is Bar.Foo)
Did I do something wrong? Is getting Parent.Child.Grandchild impossible in  LinqToSql? Is it a problem with SQLite?

Comment: Should ` options.LoadWith((MeleeWeapon mw) => mw.Attacks);` not be ` options.LoadWith<MeleeWeapon >(mw => mw.Attacks);` ? I'm guessing that's where the `InvalidCastException` is being raised.

Comment: It's inconsequential. I've tried both. The only difference is one is generic and one is not... you can see my desperate attempts at throwing everything but the kitchen sink at the problem by the huge amounts of whitespace in there.